How to pass the value of a JavaScript variable to a golang function using HTML template
I have a GO web application that is using the HTML templating feature. I am attempting to encrypt the user's password before it is submitted in a form. The steps to accomplish this are:

Use JavaScript to capture the raw value passed by the user in the input field
Call the Go encrypt function provided the in the Go template which takes in a password parameter that returns an encrypted value.
The newly encrypted value should then be forwarded as the new password value to the POST form value.

However as the listed steps are being executed the expected output is incorrect. Instead of encrypting the value of the input, it encrypts the variable name as shown below.
username: mass 
encrypted: ABZT7a7K+l7uMu2ZMq/K8ucyJKwdq0TVTmKlShBLo40iPeA3U2Pm9oTCCw==
decrypted:  ' + raw_val + '

So how do I get the JavaScript value passed into the encrypt function as opposed to the variable name being passed in? I am not very familiar with JavaScript, so either I am concatenating the strings incorrectly or I could be trying the impossible but I am not aware.
Below is the HTML source code I have in the template.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<title>Buy Bot</title>
<body>
  <form name="login" action="/login" method="POST" onsubmit="encrypt()">
    <div>
    <label for="username">username:</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder={{.KycInfo}} required>
    <div>
    </br>
    <div>
    <label for="password">password:</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div>
      remember me <input id="rememberme" type="checkbox" name="rememberme">
    </div>
    </br>
    <div>
    <input type="submit" value="login">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

<script  
  type="text/javascript">
  function encrypt(){
    var raw_val = document.getElementById("password").value
    console.log("password: ",raw_val)
    let encrypted = '{{.Encrypt "' + raw_val + '"}}'
    console.log("encrypted: ",encrypted)
    document.login.password.value = encrypted;
    return true;
  } 
</script>



You can't pass a JavaScript variable value to a Go function using a template (the template will be already generated on the client when assigning a value to the JavaScript variable).
In a login form, you usually send the raw password value and encrypt/hash it server-side. You should already be securely sending the password by using SSL.

Note that encrypting the password client-side, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78920352/26956009, can be a security risk since you'll be leaking your secret key.

Exactly that is why I was going for this route

The issue you're encountering arises because the Go template is trying to evaluate the expression at the time the template is rendered, not when the JavaScript runs in the browser. Therefore, instead of passing the JavaScript variable raw_val to the Go function {{.Encrypt}}, the template engine sees it as a literal string and tries to resolve it before the page is sent to the browser.
To solve this, you should handle the encryption entirely within the JavaScript. You can't call Go functions from JavaScript directly. Instead, you should implement the encryption logic in JavaScript. Here's how you could do it:
Remove the call to Go's Encrypt function from the template.
Implement the encryption directly in JavaScript. For this, you could use a JavaScript library like CryptoJS for encryption.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<title>Buy Bot</title>
<body>
  <form name="login" action="/login" method="POST" onsubmit="encrypt()">
    <div>
      <label for="username">username:</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder={{.KycInfo}} required>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div>
      <label for="password">password:</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div>
      remember me <input id="rememberme" type="checkbox" name="rememberme">
    </div>
    </br>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="login">
    </div>
  </form>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function encrypt(){
      var raw_val = document.getElementById("password").value;
      console.log("password: ", raw_val);

      // Encrypting the password using CryptoJS
      var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(raw_val, "your-secret-key").toString();
      console.log("encrypted: ", encrypted);

      document.login.password.value = encrypted;
      return true;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>




This was my original route but this is an un-secure route as mentioned by goproxy.dev
